# Second mysqli connection rewrite error on first connection

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$db1 = new mysqli($db_host.'1', $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name); // Unknown host
if ($db1->connect_errno) { echo 'Error: '.$db1->connect_error.'<br />'; } else { echo 'Ok<br />'; }
$db2 = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name); // Connection OK
if ($db1->connect_errno) { echo 'Error: '.$db1->connect_error.'<br />'; } else { echo 'Ok<br />'; }
```

Why the above example will output:

```
Error: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost1' (11)
Ok
```

Comment: The error message is clear. There is no server `localhost1`.

Comment: `$db_host.'1'` => `$db_host` ?

Comment: Error in this listing for example. Why second message is clear, if i try to show error for first connection?

Comment: @JohnConde He uses the "old" connection `$db1` after establishing connection with `$db2` to do the checking. Now he wants to know why the error message in `$db1->connect_errno` gets removed.

Comment: Because once $db1 fails, the error displays and then the connection is killed. when line 4 runs again, $db1 is an empty variable, so the else condition takes over and you see "Ok".

Answer (score 0):

Check all of your variables.  I assume you're trying to connect to 2 different DB's on the same server?

Here are the issues:
Line 1 and 3 are trying to connect to the exact same dbname (that needs to change)

Line 2 and 4 are identical...change line 4 from db1 to db2

change $db_host.'1' to $db_host

Comment: You are dont't understand me... I know about lines are identical. It's not a bug!
"He uses the "old" connection $db1 after establishing connection with $db2 to do the checking. Now he wants to know why the error message in $db1->connect_errno gets removed. –  Tom 5 mins ago"

Comment: Because once $db1 fails, the error displays and then the connection is killed.  when line 4 runs again, $db1 is an empty variable, so the else condition takes over and you see "Ok".

Comment: You can remove second line and you also get "ok". So, mysqli always return object, even if connection failed. Why second connection clear or rewrite data in first connection object?

Comment: Try commenting out the second AND third line and see if you still get the Ok result...

Comment: It's obvious that in this case, I see the error ... What do you mean by that?